# NiFi-1.0.0 GetFile related

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a flow, the first processor is GetFile which reads from a source dir and runs every [x] secs or minutes.
If I would copy a file in the source dir and GetFile starts to read the file at that moment in time, would I get partial data over the wire ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes that can happen. A common pattern is to copy the file into the source dir with a dot at the front such that it gets excluded from the GetFile at first, then once the file is complete it can be renamed and then GetFile would pick up the entire thing.